# Using Chalink oracle for ethereum application

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, chainlink, oracles, off-chain

Is using any Offchain data like chainlink oracle is safe as far security is concerned for any ethereum application and how does ethereum ensures that is is safe to use them

Comment: Is there a specific part of using oracles you are concerned about? This playlist might be useful 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tIUHQ7sDoaU&list=PLVP9aGDn-X0Q3qBME3T9sBMw66xPsglMA&index=1

Answer (score 0):

Incorporating off-chain data sources like Chainlink oracles can bring valuable enhancements to Ethereum applications. However, it's important to note that Ethereum itself doesn't guarantee the safety of these data sources. To address this, Ethereum relies on decentralized oracles, reputation systems, data validation, smart contract audits, and active community involvement.

These measures aim to reduce risks and ensure the security and reliability of off-chain data. Developers should be diligent in integrating and auditing their smart contracts to ensure they are using off-chain data properly and minimizing potential vulnerabilities.